# SELECT WHERE JOINED TABLE HAS CERTAIN DATA ONLY in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables which is one to many.

**judgement table**

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

**category table**

| id | judgement_id | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |

Now, if my filter is WHERE category_id = 1. I will get the judgement_id = 2 only since my filtering should be absolute.

I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM judgement
INNER JOIN category ON category.judgement_id = judgement.id
WHERE category.category_id IN (1)
GROUP BY judgement.id
```

But I also get the judgement_id = 1.

Thanks

Comment: No, if your filter is `WHERE category_id = 1`, you will get 1 & 2 `judgement_id` since both have `category_id=1`. Just look at you `category` table. What exactly are you trying to get? Maybe you want `WHERE category_id = 1` and `judgement_id` only occur once?

Comment: You must check that this `category_id` value is the only value for `judgement_id`. You may: a) compare the amounts of this category and any category - they must be equal; b) check that the amount of distinct category values is 1; c) check that the row with the category which is not equal to specified one not exists.

Comment: @Akina Can you give an example query? I didn't quite get the explanation

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE category 
> SELECT 1 id,  1 judgement_id, 1 category_id UNION ALL
> SELECT 2, 1,  2 UNION ALL
> SELECT 3, 1,  3 UNION ALL
> SELECT 4, 2,  1;
> SELECT * FROM category;
> ```
>
> | id | judgement_id | category_id |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | 2 | 1 | 2 |
> | 3 | 1 | 3 |
> | 4 | 2 | 1 |

> ```
> -- compare the amounts of this category and any category - they must be equal
> SELECT judgement_id
> FROM category
> GROUP BY judgement_id
> HAVING SUM(category_id = 1) = COUNT(*);
> ```
>
> ```
> | judgement_id |
> | -----------: |
> |            2 |
> ```

> ```
> -- check that the amount of distinct category values is 1
> SELECT judgement_id
> FROM category
> GROUP BY judgement_id
> HAVING MAX(category_id) = 1
>    AND COUNT(DISTINCT category_id) = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> | judgement_id |
> | -----------: |
> |            2 |
> ```

> ```
> -- check that the row with the category which is not equal to specified one not exists
> SELECT DISTINCT judgement_id
> FROM category
> WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
>                    FROM category cc
>                    WHERE category.judgement_id = cc.judgement_id
>                      AND cc.category_id != 1 )
> ```
>
> ```
> | judgement_id |
> | -----------: |
> |            2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=98b4f60282120b9aebb84efc74a23bb9)*

Comment: Does this apply if where category_id is 1,2, and 3? which is judgement_id = 1? I can't seem to work it like that. Thank you btw. :)

Comment: @SeeMore This is another, more common, task. Study "logical division".